# Reference request: Relativizing a formula with respect to a predicate in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I am looking for a reference to the following, I searched far and wide but perhaps I am using the wrong terminology or something.

Let $\tau$ be a relational vocabulary. For $\mathfrak{A}$ a structure in $\operatorname{Struct}(\tau)$, $P(x,y)$ a predicate and $y$ in the domain of $\mathfrak{A}$, let $\mathfrak{A}^{P(\cdot, y)}$ be the induced substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ with domain consisting of $y$ and all $x$ such that $P(x,y)$ is true. The result I want is that for every FO formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots, x_j)$ there is a formula $\phi^{P}(y,x_1,\ldots, x_j)$ such that for all $(y,x_1,\ldots, x_j)$ in the domain of $\mathfrak{A}$ with $P(x_i,y)$ true for all $i\in [j]$, we have

$$ (\mathfrak{A},y,x_1,\ldots, x_j)  \models \phi^P\quad\text{iff}\quad (\mathfrak{A}^{ P(\cdot, y) },x_1,\ldots, x_j)\models \phi. $$

This formula should likely be obtained by replacing in $\phi$ every occurrence of $\exists x \psi$ by $\exists x ( P(x,y) \rightarrow \psi)$ and similarly for $\forall$.

I managed to prove something to this effect myself already. However, I know this is (a simple variant of) a fairly simple result, and $\phi^P$ is sometimes called the relativization of $\phi$. But I need the result as a reference, so I would rather just refer to somewhere where it is clearly stated instead of proving it myself. Wherever I found this technique the authors simply state it as fact or hand wave.

**Note:** I am working with a relational vocabulary, this is not strictly necessary but is there to omit some requirements that the constants be in $\mathfrak{A}^{P(\cdot,y)}$ and similar problems for functions.

Comment: hi Permuton. may I ask what the context where you will be using this is? (is it in a paper, an assignment, lecture notes, etc...?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom It will be used in a paper. That's why I would like a reference instead of the proof I did mysefl :) Especially since I just need for a small 'technicality'

Comment: that makes sense! :) I don't know of a reference, though I'm absolutely sure there is one... but in the worst case if you're not able to find one it doesn't seem completely out of the question to me to just write "the relativization of $\phi$ to $P$"!

Comment: (eg you could just give the inductive definition of $\phi^P$, and then write a remark along the lines of "a proof by induction shows ...etc")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Theorem 5.1.1 in Hodges *Model Theory* (p. 203) or Theorem 4.2.1 in Hodges *A Shorter Model Theory* (p. 101). Hodges only discusses the case of relativization to a unary predicate $P(x)$, but you can obtain your version parameterized by $y$ by just replacing $P(x)$ everywhere by $P(x,y)$.

By the way, what you suggested is not quite right: $\exists x\psi$ should be replaced by $$\exists x(P(x,y)\land \psi),$$ while $\forall x\psi$ should be replaced by $$\forall x(P(x,y)\rightarrow \psi).$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already found this reference but expanding to binary predicates and explaining that the logic Hodges uses includes FO takes roughly the same amount of space as a proof :) I should probably accept that there will no reference saying precisely what I need.

Comment: @Permuton I agree with Atticus in the comments that for a research paper, stating the result and giving a reference to Hodges with no further explanation would be sufficient. Most readers will know what you mean by "the relativization of $\phi$ to $P$", and if they don't, they should be able to fill in the details for themselves after looking at Hodges. One is allowed to expect a bit of mathematical maturity from the reader of a research paper.